# getting error !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize' when the video is about to finish

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to resize a video using cv2.resize to accelerate face detecting, my code runs fine if I stopped the process before it finishes, it will work just fine showing me the progress and the output just before terminating the process however if I let it finish on its own I get the above error and no output.
My assumption is at the end of the video there is not frame to get its size to resize it, how to end the loop before that happens?

```py
#this code uses openCV library to detect faces
#in a video provided in the same project folder
#a brief description is written under important lines of code describing its job

import cv2
import time
#importing necessarily libraries
start = time. time()


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\Users\\moh00\\PycharmProjects\\try1\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\data\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
#choosing the right face classifier provided with openCV and importing it

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('thor.mp4')
#loading the video using cv2.VideoCapture (incase you want to use a webcam put 0 at file name or the webcam number ordering number)

fourCC = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
#codec to used to write the video

out = cv2.VideoWriter('thorCV.avi',fourCC, 29.97, (1920,1080))
#output the video after detection, must use same FPS, (x,y)RES


while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
# reduce the res in quarter for faster processing

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(small_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces1 = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,1.2,3)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces1:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x*4,y*4), ((x+w)*4,(y+h)*4), (0,0,255), 2)
# scaling back to draw the rectangle at the right position


    out.write(frame)
    #output the video

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    #show the video for face detection

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
#a line used to end the loop (pressing q in the keyboard will terminate the process)


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
out.release()

end = time. time()
print(end - start)
```

Answer (score 1):

my assumption was correct adding this if condition fixed my problem

```py
    if ret:
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        # reduce the res in quarter for faster processing
    else:
        break
```